# AWS Athena unnest with left join not working

Tags: arrays, json, left-join, presto, amazon-athena

I have a nested JSON structure where I want to unnest one JSON subtree. Either A or B is filled and event.type is marked as 'A' or 'B'. Here's two simplified examples:

```
{
  "event": {
        "event_type": "A",
        "time": 1599692445083,
        "A" : {
            "name": "item1",
            "revenue": 100
        }
      }
  }
}

{
  "event": {
        "event_type": "B",
        "time": 1599692445083,
        "B" : {
            "items" : [
                {"name": "item2", revenue" : 10},
                {"name": "item3", revenue" : 20},
            ]
        }
      }
  }
}
```

Query works so far, but I have the issue that UNNEST just works with cross join and thus I'm loosing all "A" events as I would need left join. Please note I do multiple aggregates, so calculating the sum alone on an easier way would be sufficient.

```
select
    from_unixtime( (floor(event.time/1000) / (60 * 60))  *60*60) as event_hour,
    count(*) filter(where event.event_type = 'A') as A_items,
    count(*) filter(where event.event_type = 'B') as B_items
FROM mydb.event_table
   left join unnest(event.B.items) as t(b)
WHERE
    year=2020 and month=9 and day=18 and hour=1
GROUP BY
    from_unixtime( (floor(event.time/1000) / (60 * 60))  *60*60),
```

For *cross join unnest* query executes, but as A does not have an item Array I do not get any entries counted. For *left join unnest* I got an error message (funny enough it states 'left' there as well):

```
mismatched input 'where' expecting {'join', 'cross', 'inner', 'left', 'right', 'full', 'natural', 'using', 'on', 'tablesample'}
```

Is there a way to use left join in unnest in Athena?

Comment: I am actually not sure that you need the whole unnest at all, wouldn't this work?
`count(*) filter(where event.event_type = 'A') as A_items,
 sum(cardinality(event.B.items)) filter(where event.event_type = 'B') as B_items`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a work around for the mentioned use case to not loose entries when UNNESTING using cross join. It looks ugly but does the job until Athena will support newer Presto functionality.

Instead of

```
   left join unnest(event.B.items) as t(b)
```

one can rewrite the left join to a cross join with coalesce:

```
   cross join unnest(coalesce(event.B.items, array[null])) as t(b)
```

Comment: This wouldn't work for rows with empty arrays, right? For that you'd need something like `IF(event.B.items IS NULL OR cardinality(event.B.items) = 0, ARRAY[NULL], event.B.items)`. Or are empty arrays somehow equivalent to `NULL` in the eyes of `COALESCE`?

Comment: In our use case we just want all items. So we're replacing a non exiting (=null) match by an array with one null element (resulting in a null row for the join). Note ```null != array[null]```. Otherwise it would do nothing. ```COALESCE``` replaces *null* by *array[null]* which does the trick). If there is an array with no element in there, it should not unnest and you would need to replace it by an array with a null element like you mentioned. Hope this helps.

Comment: you would need to take care of the case where `event.B.items` is an empty array too

Answer (score 3):

Athena is based on Presto .172
`LEFT JOIN` with `UNNEST` was added in [Presto 319](https://trino.io/docs/current/release/release-319.html)

> Add support for INNER and OUTER joins involving UNNEST.

I would assume Athena does not support this until they

- upgrade to newer Presto release
- backport the feature to their fork

In the meantime, you can run latest greatest version of Presto:

- using EMR 6.1, choose "PrestoSQL" component
- using [Starburst's Presto as a Service on AWS](https://www.starburstdata.com/presto-aws-cloud/)

Also, as @GMB pointed out, the `JOIN` requires the `ON` clause (can be as simple as `ON true`).

Comment: Thanks for the useful comment about the used presto version . Even though it feels uncommon JOIN does not enforce using ON in Presto. If not defines, it simply does a cartesian product when joining. See Presto documentation for JOIN: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#joins Using UNNEST a dummy "on" clause is not needed. See: https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest

Comment: @supernova, that's only true for a CROSS JOIN. LEFT/RIGHT/FULL/INNER JOIN do require an ON clause. The reason it's not needed for UNNEST in the example you mentioned is that UNNEST (which is just a table function), is being used in the context of a CROSS JOIN (or implicit join)